# SQL Server database growing exceptionally large after database to database import

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Something rather odd is going on and hope someone can shed some light on it. I have two databases with two tables. I'm combining them into another database to consolidate. The two I am exporting from have columns at 8000 (crazy right?) and the ones its going into are normal at 50, some at 75. Everything went in without truncation errors but the new database is literally 10 times the size of the other databases.

Example. DB 1 is 58 gigs and db2 is 78 or so. Together, once imported into the consolidated DB... 1.2 terabytes! What's going on here and can I shrink that or have to kick it out to another DB or text file to reimport for a normal sized DB. Should be like 140 gig at best or a tad more but over a TB???

Also I should add I'm using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and some columns went from text to string, so there was some conversion going on... and the log file is not included in the 1.2 TB either...

Comment: Weird, can you just shrink the MDF?

Comment: Literally of the 1.2 TB... 2 gig of free space in the MDF and log file is at a gig...

Comment: What do the table definitions look like? Could it be a case of the column types you are using in the new set of tables take up more space than the old tables?

Comment: So you have two tables, you could try running `sp_spaceused 'tablename'` on each to see which is bigger. Do you have alot of indexes set up on either of the tables?

Comment: I guess that is possible. In some cases I am going from a column that is text to one that is string... but this seems unusually large for a conversion issue.. .but could be...

Comment: rsbarro may be on to something. Viewing "shrink database" says 2 gigs of space yet that SP shows 75 gigs usused in just that one (of 4) tables... and shows a ton in reserve. A normal "shrink" will sure that yes??

Comment: Also... not one index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I determined... the wildly increased size must of had to do with the conversion of data. As a test I created a duplicate database with tables of the same type and size (varchar) and did a database-to-database transfer basically copying all tables to the new DB and the size is "normal" and not a wild number. Still not entirely sure why it went wild with growth originally, but if anyone runs into the same issue, even though its a pain in the butt to duplicate ... it will work....